# porting a java6 swing code to java5

Tags: swing, java-6, java-5

I have some code that uses JTabbedPane java 6 extension (it uses the method indexOfTabComponent(Component))
How can I make this code compatible with java 5?

Please don't tell me to upgrade to java 6, I can't.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to extend [JTabbedPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html) circa 1.5 and implement `indexOfTabComponent(Component)` in your extension, then switch your code to use your new extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot with [`insertTab()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html), as seen in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484251).