# how to add Jpanel in each jList item in java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlist

I want to add `jPanel` in each `jlist` item in java dynamically. where `jPanel` contain a button and progressbar and label. And `jlist` contains that `jpanel` in each tuple in `jlist`.

Comment: Note edit to answer with example code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A JList cannot hold components, but instead can only hold *renderings* of a component. So in short, your request is not directly possible. **But**, you can have something similar with a JTable that holds editable renderings of JButton and your JProgressBar and JLabel. The big difference with the JTable is that its cells are editable, so that the button can "work" in this environment.

You can find more by looking at the links to the Swing tutorials and other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing)

---

Example code:

- Note that this uses Rob Camicker's amazingly wonderful ButtonColumn. The article can be found [here](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/), and the code can be found [here](http://www.camick.com/java/source/ButtonColumn.java).
- This also borrows from mKorbel's StackOverflow answer code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7036206/522444)
- As well as TrashGod's code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5559747/522444)

---

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ComplexTableEg extends JPanel {
   private CTTableModel tableModel = new CTTableModel();
   private JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);

   public ComplexTableEg() {
      StartProgressAction startProgressAction = new StartProgressAction(
            "Start Progress", KeyEvent.VK_S);
      new ButtonColumn(table, startProgressAction, 0);
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(new ProgressRenderer());

      JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
      buttonPanel.add(new JButton(new AddRowAction("Add Row", KeyEvent.VK_A)));

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
   }

   private class AddRowAction extends AbstractAction {
      public AddRowAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         int rowCount = tableModel.getRowCount() + 1;
         CTRowData ctRow = new CTRowData("Row " + rowCount);
         tableModel.addRow(ctRow);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      ComplexTableEg mainPanel = new ComplexTableEg();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Complex Table Eg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

/**
 * From mKorbel's StackOverflow answer
 * @link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7036206/522444
 *
 */
class ProgressRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
   private final JProgressBar b = new JProgressBar(0, 100);

   public ProgressRenderer() {
       super();
       setOpaque(true);
       b.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
   }

   @Override
   public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
       Integer i = (Integer) value;
       String text = "Completed";
       if (i < 0) {
           text = "Error";
       } else if (i < 100) {
           b.setValue(i);
           return b;
       }
       super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, text, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
       return this;
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class StartProgressAction extends AbstractAction {
   public StartProgressAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
      super(name);
      putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      JTable table = (JTable) e.getSource();
      int rowIndex = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());
      CTTableModel model = (CTTableModel) table.getModel();
      CTRowData row = model.getRow(rowIndex);
      row.startProcessing();
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class CTTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
   public static final String[] COLUMN_HEADERS = { "Button", "Label",
         "Progress" };
   private List<CTRowData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

   @Override
   public int getRowCount() {
      return dataList.size();
   }

   public CTRowData getRow(int rowIndex) {
      return dataList.get(rowIndex);
   }

   @Override
   public int getColumnCount() {
      return COLUMN_HEADERS.length;
   }

   @Override
   public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
      CTRowData row = dataList.get(rowIndex);
      switch (columnIndex) {
      case 0:
         return CTRowData.START_PROCESSING;
      case 1:
         return row.getText();
      case 2:
         return row.getValue();
      }
      return null;
   }

   @Override
   public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
      switch (columnIndex) {
      case 0:
         return String.class;
      case 1:
         return String.class;
      case 2:
         return Integer.class;
      }
      // should never need this default
      return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
   }

   @Override
   public String getColumnName(int column) {
      return COLUMN_HEADERS[column];
   }

   public void addRow(CTRowData row) {
      dataList.add(row);
      int firstRow = dataList.size() - 1;
      fireTableRowsInserted(firstRow, firstRow);

      row.addPropertyChangeListener(new RowDataListener(firstRow));
   }

   private class RowDataListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
      private int row;

      public RowDataListener(int row) {
         this.row = row; 
      }

      @Override
      public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
         if (CTRowData.VALUE.equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, 2);
         }
      }
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
      boolean cellEditable = false;
      if (columnIndex != 0) {
         cellEditable = false;
      } else {
         cellEditable = true;
      }
      return cellEditable;
   }
}

class CTRowData {
   public static final String VALUE = "value";
   public static final String PROCESSING = "processing";
   public static final String START_PROCESSING = "Start Processing";
   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 500;
   public static final int MAX_VALUE = 100;
   private String text;
   private boolean processing = false;
   private int value = 0;
   private Random random = new Random();
   private SwingPropertyChangeSupport pcSupport = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(
         this);

   public CTRowData(String text) {
      this.text = text;
   }

   public boolean isProcessing() {
      return processing;
   }

   public void setProcessing(boolean processing) {
      boolean oldValue = this.processing;
      boolean newValue = processing;
      this.processing = processing;
      pcSupport.firePropertyChange(PROCESSING, oldValue, newValue);
   }

   public void startProcessing() {
      if (processing) {
         return;
      }
      setProcessing(true);
      setValue(0);
      new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener()).start();
   }

   public String getText() {
      return text;
   }

   public int getValue() {
      return value;
   }

   public void setValue(int value) {
      int oldValue = this.value;
      int newValue = value;
      this.value = value;
      pcSupport.firePropertyChange(VALUE, oldValue, newValue);
   }

   public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      pcSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         int temp = value;
         temp += 5 + random.nextInt(10);
         temp = Math.min(temp, MAX_VALUE);
         setValue(temp);
         if (temp >= MAX_VALUE) {
            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
            setProcessing(false);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Well if you write a custom `ListCellRenderer`, it _is_ possible: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer.

Comment: @dudeprgm: Most of it is possible except for the creation of a *responsive* button. Again, that's where the JTable is different from the JList. Not only can it show multiple columns of renderings, where the JList can only show one column, it also allows its cells to be editable, making the rendered button act as if it is functioning.

Comment: @dudeprgm: please see example program above. If you can replicate this using a JList and a custom ListCellRenderer, please do so, post your answer here, comment back to me to notify me, and let me up-vote it.

Comment: Sorry, you were right. It's possible to render the button, but not make it functional. I was able to forward the `MouseEvent` to the cell renderer `JPanel` using `dispatchEvent()`, but I wasn't able to get it to the `JButton`. Maybe with a little more work it could be done, but just using a `JTable` would be a much better approach. +1