# Can I use two swing Timers inside one class of application to make asynchronous tasks on JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, timer

What is the best practice to make asynchronous operations inside one class of application? Adding two timers is a good idea?

Answer (score 4):

All instances of [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) share a single thread; use as many as otherwise make sense in your program. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3484251/230513) uses one for each tab's progress.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of asynchronous operations? If you just need to schedule something asynchronously you can use SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). If you want to do it after certain time or repeat at fixed interval use the timer.

Comment: I have class which implements ActionListener, and so far I have 1 timer. I need n number of Timers in order to draw on JPanel shapes each one after some specified time. But I have only one actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) in this class. How to make it work?

Comment: You will have to add a new action listener for another timer. You can easily create an inner class for same.