# How to create invisible button on background of animated GIF?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, gif

I was using swing to create a program/start menu for my java program. What I want is for my program to play an animated GIF in the background, while an invisible button over a certain section of the gif (which only reveals its presence if you mouse over it). My problems are thus:

A) I am not sure how to get the animated gif to play while to program waits for a button press.
B) How do I make a JButton invisible?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

-JXP

Comment: *"My problems are thus:"*  ..Complaints from the users about the 'unusable GUI'?  'Invisible buttons' - blech!  Make them visible or don't put them in any GUI you expect me to use.  What is this GUI?  A children's game?  ( And if it is, I reserve the right to change my mind and quite like it. ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson The buttons aren't invisible, see, but what i want the buttons to do is the animated gif contains the button...for example, the gif is a gif and i want a section of the gif (it has the word start on it) to be the button, not one of the default java buttons cause then it just wouldn't fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I never used `gif` or `animated gif` in the `Swing`, but you can use for that this code

[image]                 [image]

```
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class MyToggleButton extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Icon errorIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
    private Icon infoIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");
    private Icon warnIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon");

    public MyToggleButton() {
        final JButton toggleButton = new JButton();
        toggleButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        toggleButton.setBorder(null);
        toggleButton.setFocusable(false);
        toggleButton.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        toggleButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        toggleButton.setIcon((errorIcon));
        toggleButton.setSelectedIcon(infoIcon);
        toggleButton.setRolloverIcon((infoIcon));
        toggleButton.setPressedIcon(warnIcon);
        toggleButton.setDisabledIcon(warnIcon);
        add(toggleButton);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyToggleButton t = new MyToggleButton();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 You can also implement `Icon` to do the animation, as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3484251/230513).

Comment: stupid me, forgetting to set this as the correct answer. there you go :)