# Progress Bar used as Health Bar

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar, jprogressbar

I am making a java game that has a sidebar that displays a player's health. I want the bar to be like a progress bar which is along the lines of the picture below:

[image]

Would a progress bar be capable enough to accomplish this? If not, what will?

Comment: I dont know enough about the project, but I assume there may be some graphical elements. If there are then it should be simple enough to just draw two rectanges on top of each other and set the top one to be some percentage of the width of the bottom one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an "official" answer, then yes, a JProgressBar can do this easily. I suggest that you give it a try and let us know how it works out, especially if you have any problems with it.

Comment: +1 `JProgressBar` leverages the look & feel; also consider a custom [`ProgressBarUI`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8886795/230513) or a [`ProgressIcon`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3484251/230513).