# Customizing a bit complex style for JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

When user press on Harris(Green) button as shown in GreenButton Image the OP1 button will get Green color with any icon upon it with a timer underneath it....first image is showing harris button

[image]

when we will click on harris button other button with any background color will get shape like this as shown in down image

[image]

this button will contain any icons..(one on left one on right) and two timers and divided color.

> EDIT:1
>   Question is that I don't have idea how to customize my second(OP1) button like this one

Comment: *"it will be great if any one can help me..."*  It will also be great if you can: 1) Use your shift key at the start of sentences to make the text easier to read. 2) Fix that stuck '.' key. 3) Ask a question.  What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

make it a JPanel with a MouseListener. 
That way you can "play" inside the Component.

Comment: if i do't get anything with button than i will try your idea

Comment: When you want to stick to JButton, you can also use HTML in there.
A bit tricky, but that also works.

Answer (score 2):

basic view

- use `JToggleButton` with `CardLayout` (switch betweens two cards by determine `JToggleButton.isSelected()`)
- only `JFrames ContentPane (BorderLayout)` and `JPanel(FlowLayout)` has implemented `LayoutManager` in API, for rest of `JComponents` to have to add proper one

2nd. view

- put opaque `JPanels` ([or JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575641/how-returns-xxxsize-from-jcomponents-added-to-the-jlabel)) to the `JToggleButton`, use `GridLayout`
- put proper `LayoutManager` to `JPanels`, then to add the rest `JComponent` / `Icons`

Comment: Gread idea to use cardLayout with JToggleButton...but i have 1 problem there are three states of button..1-is not pressed,, 2 is pressed after 1 button(in this situation button will only have green color like harris button) , and 3rd is pressed after 2 buttons in this state it will have 2 colors as shown in picture..

Comment: `isPressed`, `isArmed` e.i. [are implemented in ButtonModel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5755124/714968)

Comment: `isPresses` is internal status of `JToggleButton`, you can to determine from `ItemListener`, `ActionListener` or `Property(Change)Listener`

Answer (score 2):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3484251/230513), you can implement the `Icon` interface to render any desired appearance and update the time remaining dynamically.

Comment: thnaks sir and i will definately look at it.