# How to make a JProgress bar with a gradient

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar, tablecellrenderer

I am using swing and wanting to make my JProgress bar look more attractive by adding a soft gradient to it that matches the theme of the app.

My progress bar is in a JTable cell which i have working but my current example paints the cell with a gradient instead of the JProgress bar itself. I would like the cell to be plain white but the progress bar go from light grey -> to dark grey as it get more complete.

Open to not using JProgress bar if something else will do the trick. (Maybe just using the cell renderer?)

My cell renderer

```
class JPBRenderer extends JProgressBar implements TableCellRenderer {

Batch batch;

public JPBRenderer() {
    super();
    setStringPainted(true);
    setBorderPainted(false);
    setOpaque(false); //EDIT 1
    setForeground(UIConfig.backgroundColor);
}

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    batch = ((BatchTableModel)table.getModel()).getBatchForRow(row);
    setMinimum(0);
    setMaximum(batch.getQuantityToProduce());
    setValue(batch.getQuantityCompleted());
    setString(GeneralUtils.formatNumber((batch.getQuantityCompleted()/batch.getQuantityToProduce())*100, 1) + " %");
    return this;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    Color color2 = UIConfig.backgroundColor;
    Color color1 = UIConfig.backgroundColor.brighter().brighter();
    double value = 1;
    if(batch != null){
        value = batch.getQuantityCompleted()/batch.getQuantityToProduce();
    }
    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, color1, w, 0, color2);

    g2d.setPaint(gp);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

    super.paintComponent(g);
}
}
```

My Batch class contains...

```
public class Batch {
    private Integer id;
    private BigDecimal length;
    private int quantityToProduce;
    private int quantityCompleted;

    //Constructors and getters...
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: depends of L&F, why there is super.paintComponent(g); called twice in one paintComponent and then why toggling with opacity, search for custom JProgresBars, then apply this logics to XxxCellRenderer, maybe I'd be use the JLayer

Comment: The painting of the progress bar is provided by the UI delegate, you will need to create your own...

Comment: Edited post as that was bogus code, thanks.JLayer might well be a good solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a custom `ProgressBarUI`, perhaps derived from [`BasicProgressBarUI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicProgressBarUI.html) illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8886795/230513). You may be able to use the existing `paintDeterminate()` implementation as a guide. A `LinearGradientPaint` applied to a `BasicSliderUI` is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6996263/230513).

Alternatively, consider the `ProgressIcon` shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3484251/230513).